# Standard interface for beans supporting PropertyChangeListeners

Tags: java, javabeans

Is there a standard interface that can be implemented by beans supporting registration of PropertyChangeListeners? I know about [java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) which helps in implementing the listener list and firing events, but I'm looking for an interface like the following:

```
public interface PropertyChangeEventSource {
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener);
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener);
}
```

This seems like a pretty common pattern so there has to be an existing more or less standard interface for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BeanContextChild](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/beancontext/BeanContextChild.html) interface might be what you are looking for. For further information: there is a nice [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/beancontext/services.html) that deals with BeanContexts over at oracle.com.

Comment: Thanks, this is not 100% what I was looking for since it requires keeping track of a BeanContext and PropertyVetoListener. But considering no one else answered in the last month, this seems to be the only standard interface. I wonder why I did not stumble upon it myself while browsing java docs.